# Changing dword value in HKEY_USERS

Tags: vbscript, registry, wmi

I've been trying to use VBScript to change a DWORD Value in HKEY_USERS. It can find the value and tell me what it is, but it will not change the value.

```
Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
strComputer = "."
Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = ".DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Flowscape.Outlook.AddIn"
strValueName = "LoadBehavior"
oReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_USERS, strKeyPath, strValueName, 3
If Err = 0 Then
    oReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_USERS, strKeyPath, strValueName, dwValue
    WScript.Echo "HKEY_USERS\...\LoadBehavior is set to " & dwValue
Else
    WScript.Echo "Error changing dword value" & Err.Number
End If
```

This other script for changing DWORD Value in HKEY_CURRENT_USER works fine.

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
           strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Flowscape.Outlook.AddIn"
strValueName = "LoadBehavior"
oReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, 3
If Err = 0 Then
    oReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, dwValue
    WScript.Echo "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...\LoadBehavior set to " & dwValue
Else
    WScript.Echo "Error changing dword value" & Err.Number
End If
```

Comment: Most likely you don't have write access to the key you want to modify. However, the WMI registry methods fail silently, so you need to check their return code to see if something went wrong. What is the output of `rc = oReg.SetDWORDValue(HKEY_USERS, strKeyPath, strValueName, 3) : WScript.Echo rc`?

Comment: the output is 5, I don't see why i wouldn't have permission though since i can change it manually just fine.

Comment: Return code 5 means "access denied" IIRC. As for why you can change the value manually: you have UAC enabled and run Regedit in elevated mode, but not your VBScript?